# Angular2, which language should be used as the preferred one

Tags: typescript, angular, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am new to Angular 2, and I've learned that developers can use type script, ES6 and ES5 to develop, and I know that type script is the superset of ES6 and ES5.

since the syntax is totally different between type script and ES6/ES5, which one should be the prime one to use? and what is the reason?

thanks

Comment: If it's a superset, how would the syntax be totally different?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129269/angularjs-2-which-language-to-use-typescript-javascript-dart/35129511#35129511

Comment: You could either use TypeScript, or you could stick pins in your eyes. Your choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> since the syntax is totally different between type script and ES6/ES5

No. TypeScript adds *additional syntax*. Here is an image:

[image]

> which one should be the prime one to use

TypeScript

> what is the reason

Better IDE Tooling and ways to document code.

## More

My opinions on why TypeScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

This video demonstrates the tooling difference between JavaScript and TypeScript : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmKXXI_ck7w

Comment: Very big circles  :)  +1

Comment: Its a big ecosystem ;)

Answer (score 1):

As @basarat said, TypeScript is a superset of ES6. That means that you can use ES6 only if you want with TypeScript. This means that ES6 modules, class support, backticks are natively supported in TypeScript.

That being said, the three cool things with TypeScript are from my point of view:

- **Type support and type checking**. This powerful feature allows you to be sure before executing the application that you don't something that doesn't exist.

  ```
  export class SomeClass {
    someProperty: string; // property of type string
    someProperty: SomeOtherClass; // property of type SomeOtherClass

    constructor(param:string) {
      this.someProperty = new SomeOtherClass();
      // SomeOtherClass must have a property named value of type
      // string. Otherwise, you will have some compilation errors.
      this.someProperty.value = param;
    }
  }
  ```
- **Comprehensive support of decorators**. With ES6, you can't use it within constructor / method parameters. In Angular2, it's something important mainly because of constructor-based dependency injection

  ```
  // With ES6 only

  @Injectable()
  export class SomeClass {
    constructor(service) {
      this.service = service;
    }

    get parameters() {
      return [[SomeOtherClass]];
    }
  }

  // With TypeScript

  @Injectable()
  export class SomeClass {
    constructor(private service:SomeOtherClass) {
    }
  }
  ```
- **Support of interfaces**. Whereas it's only for design time (not at runtime), interfaces can be used to specify contracts of elements

  ```
  export interface SomeData {
    id:string;
    name:string;
  }

  @Injectable()
  export class SomeHttpService {
    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    executeHttpRequest():Observable<SomeData[]> {
      return this.http.get('http://...')
                 .map(res => <SomeData[]>res.json());
    }
  }
  ```