# In which language angular 2 framework is developed in?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a small question about angular 2 and it is,

**In which language angular 2 framework is developed in only Typescript or in any other languages?**

My question is different from in how many ways I can use angular 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129269/angularjs-2-which-language-to-use-typescript-javascript-dart)

Comment: It’s open source. You can, like, go and check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS 2 - Which language to use? (Typescript, Javascript, Dart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129269/angularjs-2-which-language-to-use-typescript-javascript-dart)

Comment: My question is about angular framework (source code) developed in which language not angular framework can be consumed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript

You can tell this by looking at the projects source: https://github.com/angular/angular